# Not able to load image in a slider

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, timestamp, bxslider

Hi i am using a pre built bootstrap theme, It has a slider of images, it seems to work fine with its default slider images, but when i am changing the url of images, a timestamp is being added behind it which is hindering the display of images, can anyone please tell how to remove timestamp from the image url.

The code is

```
<ul class="bxslider1 clients-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/clients/one.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/clients/two.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The timestamp that is being added is

> img/clients/one.png?timestamp=1476957097630

Is there a way i can remove this timestamp

Would appreciate any help and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function(e) { 
    var images = $('img').attr('src');
   
    var imgSrc = images;
    imgSrc = imgSrc.substring(0 , imgSrc.indexOf('?')+0);
  $('#url').html(imgSrc);
 // alert(imgSrc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bxslider1 clients-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/clients/one.png?timestamp=1476957097630" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/clients/two.png?timestamp=1476957097630" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="url"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

time stamp is there because image will not come from caching. you jst want to delete time stamp then simply serach out in js with keywoard ?timestamp and remove it.